# Kdenlive not starting

Tags: manjaro, kdenlive

Kdenlive is not starting, It shows the splash screen then closes I also tried to reinstall it and restart my PC but its still the same then, I tried to launch it from the terminal (so that I can see the error) and this was the result:

```
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltrtaudio.so
  (librtaudio.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltsox.so
  (libsox.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltrubberband.so
  (librubberband.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltopencv.so
  (libopencv_tracking.so.4.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltsdl.so
  (libSDL_image-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Invalid metadata for "jack"
Failed to parse "jack"
Invalid title/identifier for "crop_detect"
Failed to parse "crop_detect"
Invalid metadata for "telecide"
Failed to parse "telecide"
Invalid metadata for "glsl.manager"
Failed to parse "glsl.manager"
Invalid metadata for "movit.convert"
Failed to parse "movit.convert"
Invalid metadata for "movit.crop"
Failed to parse "movit.crop"
Invalid metadata for "movit.resample"
Failed to parse "movit.resample"
Invalid metadata for "movit.resize"
Failed to parse "movit.resize"
Invalid metadata for "deinterlace"
Failed to parse "deinterlace"
Invalid metadata for "avcolour_space"
Failed to parse "avcolour_space"
Invalid metadata for "avcolor_space"
Failed to parse "avcolor_space"
Invalid metadata for "avdeinterlace"
Failed to parse "avdeinterlace"
Invalid metadata for "swscale"
Failed to parse "swscale"
Invalid metadata for "swresample"
Failed to parse "swresample"
Invalid metadata for "audiochannels"
Failed to parse "audiochannels"
Invalid metadata for "audioconvert"
Failed to parse "audioconvert"
Invalid metadata for "data_feed"
Failed to parse "data_feed"
Invalid metadata for "imageconvert"
Failed to parse "imageconvert"
Unknown asset "avfilter.acompressor"
Unknown asset "avfilter.aecho"
Unknown asset "avfilter.agate"
Unknown asset "avfilter.atadenoise"
Unknown asset "avfilter.bwdif"
Unknown asset "avfilter.deblock"
Unknown asset "avfilter.dedot"
Unknown asset "avfilter.deflate"
Unknown asset "avfilter.derain"
Unknown asset "avfilter.doubleweave"
Unknown asset "avfilter.field"
Unknown asset "avfilter.framestep"
Unknown asset "avfilter.fspp"
Unknown asset "avfilter.graphmonitor"
Unknown asset "avfilter.hqdn3d"
Unknown asset "avfilter.inflate"
Unknown asset "avfilter.lagfun"
Unknown asset "avfilter.random"
Unknown asset "avfilter.removegrain"
Unknown asset "avfilter.separatefields"
Unknown asset "avfilter.shuffleplanes"
Unknown asset "avfilter.sr"
Unknown asset "avfilter.tmix"
Unknown asset "avfilter.w3fdif"
Unknown asset "avfilter.weave"
Unknown asset "avfilter.yadif"
Unknown asset "frei0r.baltan"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bgsubtract0r"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_eq_mask"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_eq_to_rect"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_hemi_to_eq"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_rect_to_eq"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_stabilize_360"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_transform_360"
Unknown asset "frei0r.delay0r"
Unknown asset "frei0r.delaygrab"
Unknown asset "frei0r.facebl0r"
Unknown asset "frei0r.facedetect"
Unknown asset "frei0r.lightgraffiti"
Unknown asset "frei0r.lightgraffiti"
Unknown asset "movit.unsharp_mask"
Unknown asset "region"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "sox"
Unknown asset "timewarp"
Unknown asset "opencv.tracker"
Unknown asset "opencv.tracker"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I reverted your tagging with "(SOLVED)" in the title. If the question has a solution and it has been posted as an answer, then accept that answer to mark the question as resolved.  You accept an answer by clicking the greyed-out check mark to the left of the answer.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: you can accept your own answer after 48 hours, so don't add "SOLVED" or anything to your question. after 48 hours passed you can come and accept your own answer, that indicates your question/problem resolved. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found the solution!

I uninstalled kdenlive >> deleted the kden folders in ~/.config >> restarted my PC >> finally installed Kdenlive and when I opened it that time it worked! 
 This may be because some configuration leeded to crash may be a theme!